# How can I further simplify $(B^c ∩ (B ∩ A)^c)^c$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm pretty sure this is equal to B, but I'm not sure how to go about reducing this step by step.  Could I use the double negative law to eliminate the complements?  I'm not positive if that would work in the current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll denote $\overline{A}=A^c$. By [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#Some_additional_laws_for_complements): $$\overline{\overline{B}\cap \overline{B\cap A}}=\overline{\overline{B}}\cup \overline{\overline{B\cap A}}$$

By the [double complement or Involution law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#Some_additional_laws_for_complements): $$=B\cup(B\cap A)$$

By the [Absorption Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#Some_additional_laws_for_unions_and_intersections) it equals $B$.

Answer (score 2):

By De Morgan's Law:

$(B^c \cap (B \cap A)^c)^c = B \cup (B \cap A) = B$

Comment: There were two unnecessary steps. See the [Absorption Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#Some_additional_laws_for_unions_and_intersections).